# How to use TypeScript definitions in VS 2015

Tags: visual-studio, typescript, visual-studio-2015

I am trying to create a TypeScript NodeJS project in VS 2015, I have installed Typings, and have used it to install TypeScript definitions for express and other node frameworks

However, when I use `/// <reference path="Scripts/typings/globals/express/index.d.ts" />` in my `.ts` file, I do not receive any intellisense when trying to use express. There are no errors, and it finds the definition file.

How can I get the TypeScript definitions to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out I was using this syntax: `var express  = require('express');`

When I should have been using this: `import express = require('express');`